# Montar tabela HTML dinamica com PHP

Tags: php

Estou com dúvida de como montar uma tabela dinâmica com PHP.

Estou montando uma tabela em HTML na qual será exibida alguns dados cadastrados em um banco de dados, ja criei o `SELECT` que traz as informações do banco de dados, mas estou com duvida de como construir o laço para exibir as informações ja que a tabela tera 4 colunas.

Tentei montar um laço `FOR` porem ele exibiu a tabela da seguinte maneira.

```
Item 1 | Item 1 | Item 1 | Item 1
Item 2 | Item 2 | Item 2 | Item 2
Item 3 | Item 3 | Item 3 | Item 3
```

Quando deveria exibir

```
Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4
Item 5 | Item 6 | Item 7 | Item 8
Item 9 | Item 10 | Item 11 | Item 12
```

Estrutura do laço

```
<?php while ( $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($executaSelect) ) { ?>
  <tr>
    <?php for ($i = 1 ; $i <= 4 ; $i++) { ?>
      <td><?php echo $linha["nome"]; ?></td>
   <?php } ?>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Veja se isto te ajuda http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/gerar-uma-lista-em-html-a-partir-de-uma-consulta-mysql-com-php

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte:

```
<?php
$i=0;
echo '<table border="0">'
while ( $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($executaSelect) ) {
    if ($i === 0) echo '<tr>'
    echo '<td>' . $linha["nome"] . '</td>';
    $i++;
    if ($i === 4) { 
        echo '</tr>'; // A cada 4 colunas fecha uma linha
        $i=0; // Zera o contador para abrir nova linha no início do loop
    }
}
if ($i > 0) echo '</tr>'; // Caso a última linha tenha menos de 4 colunas, fecha a linha
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Funciona bem só que tem um detalhe. Quando a quantidade de registros retornados da consulta ao banco de dados não for múltiplo de 4, a última linha da tabela ficará aberta, o que pode causar um grave conflito e quebrar todo o layout da página.

Comment: @bfavaretto, falha minha, o primeiro $i=0 óbviamente deveria estar fora do loop. Arrumei no exemplo.

Comment: @DanielOmine, coloquei um "fechador" para a última linha quando tiver menos de 4 colunas. Agora no máximo ela não terá o número certo de colunas. []s

Answer (score 1):

Fiz uma adaptação bem detalhada.
O código parece grande por causa dos comentários, quebras de linha, etc.
Fiz assim para ficar fácil de ler e entender o código.

```
<?php 
/*
Inicia o contador geral que será usado para comparar a quantidade de registros retornados do banco de dados.
*/
$c = 0;
/*
Inicia o contador de colunas
*/
$i = 1;
/*
Quantidade de colunas por linha
*/
$l = 4;

/*
Quantidade de registros retornados do banco de dados
*/
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($executaSelect);

/*
Itera a consulta ao banco de dados
*/
while ( $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($executaSelect) )
{
    /*
    Se o valor do contador de colunas $i for igual a 1, indica que uma nova linha deve ser aberta.
    Se uma nova linha está sendo aberta, quer dizer que uma linha anterior deve ser fechada. No entando, é preciso verificar se já passou pela primeira linha, pois antes da primeira linha não há o que ser fechado.
    Para verificar isso, podemos aproveitar o contador geral $c
    */
    if( $i <= 1 )
    {
        if( $c > 0 ){echo '</tr>'} // Fecha uma linha
        echo '<tr>'; // Abre uma linha
    }

    /*
    Escreve a coluna com o valor obtido da consulta ao banco de dados
    */
    echo PHP_EOL . '<td>' . $linha["nome"] . '</td>';

    /*
    Checagem para incrementar ou resetar o contador de colunas.
    */
    if($i <= $l )
    {
        /*
        Incrementa o valor de $i para indicar que será escrita a próxima linha 
        */
        $i++;
    }else{
        /*
        Reseta para o valor 1, pois será formada nova linha caso não tenha chegado ao final indicado pela condição $c == $row
        */
        $i = 1;
    }

    /*
    Incrementa o valor do contador geral.
    Deve ser livre, sem condicionais.
    */
    $c++;

    /*
    Verifica se encontrou o final da consulta.
    Esse passo é muito importante para evitar que a última linha fique sem a tag de fechamento pois a quantidade de registros pode ser um número que não seja múltiplo do valor definido na variável $l
    */
    if( $c == $row )
    {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
?>
```